# Find Closest Date

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to run a query that will return rows sorted by closest to today's date.

Here is some data:

```
|   date   |
|----------|
|2012-12-02|
|2012-12-04|
|2012-12-10|
|2012-12-15|
|2012-12-29|
|2013-01-02|
|2013-01-04|
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM days
    ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", date ) - strftime( "%s", 2012-12-28 ) ) ASC
```

It just returns the rows in the same order I posted above, I want to get a result like

```
|   date   |
|----------|
|2012-12-29|
|2013-01-02|
|2013-01-04|
|2012-12-15|
|2012-12-10|
|2012-12-04|
```

My date field is a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` (there's a reason I'm not storing it as a timestamp).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's always a *reason* for not storing as a timestamp, but its usually wrong :)

Comment: My reason is as follows, the device this database is on will be crossing timezones frequently, but I want the date to be unaffected by that.  If 2012-12-29 is stored in the PST timezone and then it goes to Japan, I still want it to come out as 2012-12-29, not 2012-12-30 as it would be with a timestamp.  I can't store timezone info in the database because it won't be available.

Comment: Can you try to check whether both the dates for comparison are in the same format ? Know this is silly but still give it a try.

Comment: In that case use UTC timestamps. They remain the same wherever you are.

Comment: Yes they are formatted identically.

Comment: I'll think on the timestamp thing again, but it needs to be completely timezone independent while always showing dates in the local timezone.  In the meantime, is there a way to make this work with the dates stored as I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake on the code:

```
SELECT * FROM days
    ORDER BY ABS( strftime( "%s", date ) - strftime( "%s", 2012-12-28 ) ) ASC
```

Written this way, the query will show the results just ordered by date.

The reason: `2012-12-28` will be treated as an arithmetic operation between integers. You should write `'2012-12-28'`, to indicate that this is a `date`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use strftime.

```
SELECT * FROM days
 WHERE date <= '2012-12-28'
    ORDER BY date ASC
    -- LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Small hint: this doesn't return the closest date but the dates which are before the given one.